# I have done groupby column using DataTable. Now I have to show the total value of "another number field column" with the existing groupby

Tags: datatables

I have done groupby column using DataTable as shown below.

| Project | Task | Efforts(in Hrs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Sakthi** | --------- | --------------- |
| HTML Page | designing | 2.30 |
| HTML Page | JS | 0.30 |
| HTML Page | css | 5.00 |
| **Vel** | --------- | --------------- |
| HTML Page | Tesing | 4.00 |
| HTML Page | Test Case | 4.00 |

Now I have to show the total value of "another number field column" with the existing groupby.

| Project | Task | Efforts(in Hrs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Sakthi** | --------- | **8.00** |
| HTML Page | designing | 2.30 |
| HTML Page | JS | 0.30 |
| HTML Page | css | 5.00 |
| **Vel** | --------- | **8.00** |
| HTML Page | Tesing | 4.00 |
| HTML Page | Test Case | 4.00 |

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a mock example for you. You need to make sure that you are using the rowGroup external script/stylesheet for the following. Within your rowGroup.startRender function you need to do the following:

Create a total variable, and pluck data from the row which you want to get the total (efforts), then use a reduce function to return an added value. Once you have done this, append it to the new table row.

```
var totalEfforts = rows
  .data()
  .pluck('Efforts')
  .reduce( function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
```

```js
var data = [
{
"Name" : "Sakthi",
"Project" : "HTML Page",
"Task" : "Designing",
"Efforts" : 2.5
},
{
"Name" : "Sakthi",
"Project" : "HTML Page",
"Task" : "JS",
"Efforts" : 0.5
},
{
"Name" : "Sakthi",
"Project" : "HTML Page",
"Task" : "CSS",
"Efforts" : 5
},
{
"Name" : "Vel",
"Project" : "HTML Page",
"Task" : "Testing",
"Efforts" : 4
},
{
"Name" : "Vel",
"Project" : "HTML Page",
"Task" : "Test Case",
"Efforts" : 4
}
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    columns : [
    {"data" : "Name", visible: false},
    {"data" : "Project"},
    {"data" : "Task"},
    {"data" : "Efforts"}
    ],
      order: [[2, 'asc']],
        rowGroup: {
              dataSrc: ['Name'],
          startRender: function (rows, group){
                    var totalEfforts = rows
            .data()
            .pluck('Efforts')
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
              return a + b;
            }, 0);
        
    return $('<tr/>')
                        .append( '<td colspan="2">'+group+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td>'+totalEfforts.toFixed(0)+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td/>' ); 
    
            },
            endRender: null,

        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.4/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.4/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Project</th>
          <th>Task</th>
          <th>Efforts (hrs)</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```